# Get <select> text using 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I am using following code:

```
<select class="element select medium" id="inDistrict"
        name="inDistrict" onchange="setCookie('lastvalue',this.value,1);">
```

It is not taking: this.value. What else to use to get the DropDown selected text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: .. or use jQuery's `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @BalusC - that's assuming you use jQuery, which doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This was more towards the OP, not to you :) Do I have to remove my upvote on your answer?

Comment: I upvoted your answer about hiring a webdesigner, so it seems we have a mexican standoff. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = this.selectedIndex;
var selectedText = this.options[i].text;
```

Should do it (if this is the correct context).